# Inflection points of function

Tags: calculus

> My question is how to find the inflection points $$y=\left(\frac{x-\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Can you show your work so far? Do you know the general process for finding an inflection point?

Comment: I have calculate the second derivative and it is 1/(9*(x-1)^(5/3))

Comment: i think the inflection point is (1,1/2) but the wolfram alpha says the function don't have any inflection point sorry for my English :)

Comment: You are probably right, wolfram alpha immediately checks for zeroes of the second derivative. see my answer below. P.S your english is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $x$ such that $f^{(2)}(x)=0$, meaning that there aren't any zeroes to check.

However, you must also check points where the second derivative is undefined.

$f''(x) = \frac{1}{9(x-1)^{5/3}}$ is undefined for $x=1$. Instead, check x-values that look like: $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$ for a small $\epsilon>0$.

So informally, $\frac{1}{9(.9-1)^{5/3}}=-5.1$ and $\frac{1}{9(1.1-1)^{5/3}}=5.15$. 
Since the second derivative is changing signs, there is an inflection point in the interval $[.9,1.1]$, and you are probably right that it is at $x=1$.